# With KVO in Objective-C is there a way to detect what observers my object has set on other objects?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

Let there be an object A that observers a property on object B.  Is there a way to ask A what properties it is observing and then see that it is observing a property on object B.

For for example:

```
[B addObserver:(A*)self forKeyPath:@"bytesUploaded"
                           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                        context:A_KVOContext];
```

Now is there a way to ask A what object's its observing?

Comment: I think even A doesn't know, that he is something observing. B should know, at which object call `observeValueForKeyPath...`

Comment: is this really the case‽  I wouldn't actually be surprised, just a bit disappointed...